# ReactJS: can't render api response into h2 tag but can log it to console

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, openweathermap

another strange error I'm getting with react on codepen.

I'm trying to render an api response into a `<h2>`but somehow I can't render every property.

```
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="weather-card">
        <h1>Weather For:</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.data.name}, {this.state.data.sys.country}</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.data.main.temp}</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.data.weather[0].main}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

rendering only `this.state.data.name` is no problem e.g. but if it's one object deeper it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined" ...

But I can log this exact same property to the console.

Anyone an idea?

also here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/rasmus/pen/aNGRJm

Edit: I got it working by assigning the different properties as their own state properties like this:

```
success: (data) => {
            self.setState({
              city: data.name,
              temp: data.main.temp,
              weather: data.weather[0].main,
              isLoading: false
            });
            console.log(self.state.data.main.temp)
          },
```

but this is a bit hacky...

Comment: `this.state.data` is not a object. Its an array. Correct syntax will be `this.state.data[0]`

Comment: 401 Authorization Required

Comment: Yeah that somehow Happened 15 mins ago

Comment: The Problem seems to be in your data structure... i changed the URL(JSON) and it runs as suspected: http://codepen.io/DoubleU23/pen/dMerOg?editors=0010 (although only with the console open, but that seems to be a codepen bug?)

Comment: found the error that made the 401 now. Now the api call works again.

Comment: and here you can see the data structure: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lon=7&lat=51&&APPID=b098c3b0475b140208e29236e37d7d04&units=metric

Comment: Did you try with: <h2>{this.state.data.name + ', ' + this.state.data.sys.country}</h2> ? (only one child expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your codepen, but I had no problems to get it to work.
It took two changes to make it work:

- changed your `setState()` (inside your Ajax call) to include `data: data`. To make sure you get a full (reference to) data object into state.
- changed your render code to include `this.state.data.sys.country`

And it renders fine, with country.

Here is a [link to edited codepen](http://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/grzyVo?editors=0010).
(hope this link works)

Comment: well that's how my initial codepen also looked like. strange. but thank you :) forked yours now to code ahead ;)